# d3.max returns different values for tsv and json (same content)

Tags: json, csv, d3.js, max

I started working with d3.
I have two datasets, one in tsv and another one in json, with the same content.

TSV:

```
x    y
1    5
5    15
99   105
101  104
```

My code for tsv:

```
<script>
   d3.tsv("data/data.tsv", function(error, data) {
       console.log(d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.x; }));
       console.log(d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y; }));
   });
</script>
```

d3.max returns in this case for x = 99, and y = 5

When i do the same with hardcoded json structure:

```
 var data =  [
              { "x" : 1, "y" : 5 },
              { "x" : 5, "y" : 15 },
              { "x" : 99, "y" : 105 },
              { "x" : 101, "y" : 104 },
             ];

 console.log(d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.x; }));
 console.log(d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y; }));
```

it returns the correct values, x = 101, y = 105.

So what am i doing wrong ?
I checked, that tsv file contains realy only one tab, between values

Comment: tsv treating it as string use `d3.tsv.parse(string[, accessor])`

Comment: The TSV version doesn't convert the values to numbers, so the max calculation is performed on string values. String comparisons work differently than Number comparisons, so you get a different result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
d3.tsv.parse(string[, accessor])
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said in the comments, you need to convert x and y to numeric values.  To do this pass an [accessor](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#csv) function which will operate on each row to coerce the values:

Try this:

```
   d3.tsv("data/data.tsv", 
     function(d){
        return {
          x: +d.x, //<-- convert to float from string 
          y: +d.y
        }
     },
     function(error, data) {
       console.log(d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.x; }));
       console.log(d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y; }));
     }
   );
```